# Is there a way to create shortcuts on an external hard drive (in Windows 7) that actually work across computers?

Tags: windows-7

As in, if my external hard drive is labeled K: on PC1, then I might have a shortcut to K:/Books. But then if I move the external hard drive to another computer, it might be labeled M:, and the shortcut will fail to work

I know that I can change the drive letters, but the issue is that the drive name often changes if I insert the hard drive into a different USB port (even on the same computer).

Comment: When I was doing PortableApps.com work, I wrote a little utility that would create shortcuts on your desktop when you ran it that would change based on the drive letter. Think I called it UUPADA. I can probably dig up the code if you'd like.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use batch files
Create your batch file scripts using %~d0 as the drive letter and colon. %~d0 is replaced by the drive containing the script. So if on one machine the external drive is F %~d0 is equivalent to F: On another machine the external drive is W %~d0 is equivalent to W:

All my scripts are this way because I use my thumb drive in 100s of machines

Comment: +1: This is how Windows does it also for your roaming profiles.